# How to get the complete autocomplete list on focus using asp.net autocomplete extender?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an Ajax autocomplete extender, and it is working fine. However, I want display the entire list on focus of that textbox.

Is there a way it can be done using the Ajax autocomplete extender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set property minimumprefixlength = 0 .